# Rails 5, Rspec: Environment data not found in the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After upgrading a Rails app to Rails 5, running RSpec tests gives me the following error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

    bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

However, that `bin` does not exist and I can't seem to generate it with `bundle binstubs rails` or with `rake rails:update:bin`.

I have also tried:

```
rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
rake db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

There is a related issue on Github [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23279).

How can I address this error?

Comment: Generally: this is a terrible, over-engineered, over-complicated change. `env RAILS_ENV={{whatever}} bin/rake db:migrate spec` used to work just fine

Answer (score 89, accepted):

New Rails 5 command to generate binstubs:

```
rails app:update:bin
```

Allows me to run the solution as the error suggested:

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

Tip from @max comment: If you are using `database_cleaner` and this error keeps popping up then change your config to:

```
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(
  :truncation,
  except: %w(ar_internal_metadata)
)
```

Comment: If you are using `database_cleaner` and this error keeps popping up then change your config to `DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, except: %w(ar_internal_metadata)` - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/445

Comment: omg, the db_cleaner solution works! :P didn't know the env was set in that table.

Comment: What file does this code go for minitest? Error still ocurring with code in test/test_helper.rb

Comment: `database_cleaner >= 1.6.2` must [have](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/issues/445) [fixed](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/pull/487) the issue. Do note that if you're running CI tests on a server, all projects that are build there should have `database_cleaner >= 1.6.2`.

Comment: That `%w(ar_internal_metadata)` workaround did not work for me.  (Rails 6, cucumber-rails 2.0.0, mysql).  Any other ideas?

Comment: ^^ and database_cleaner 1.7.0 (so it's def not fixed in 1.6.2)

Comment: It appears this was fixed as of [1.8.2](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner/blob/master/History.rdoc#182-2020-02-01-).

Running a test suite with repeat has yet to bring the message back up after:

1. Updating the gem
2. Resetting my environment data

Answer (score 13):

All of the above answers are correct, however, if you're in a more unique project such as developing a rails engine with a concept of a schema (hacky, I know) and your migration fails for some reason, you can re-run it without the check that throws this exception. Example:

`rake environment db:{drop,create,migrate} DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1`

Answer (score 12):

For me, this error was followed by a similar one asking for a migration.

This did the trick: `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 8):

fix for jenkins before you drop database you should execute `db:environment:set` with `|| true`, so the command doesn't abort:

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test || true
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, I had to do a mixture of things:

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

This would make things work, and then I had to review my migrations, I was adding a null:false into a relationship and that added a bug, the migration was cancelled and didn't finish

Answer (score 1):

I had to drop my database for tests and create it again:

1. `psql`
2. `DROP DATABASE your_db_name_test;`
3. `bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test`

After that the warning `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test` disappeared.

Comment: 4. `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to see this error while using parallel_tests gem then you need to run below command for each DB. Just increase TEST_ENV_NUMBER.

```
TEST_ENV_NUMBER=1 bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
TEST_ENV_NUMBER=2 bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

This helped me fix the problem when I was testing parallel_tests with knapsack_pro gem https://github.com/KnapsackPro/knapsack_pro-ruby#parallel_tests-with-knapsack_pro-on-single-ci-machine