# Deploying rails app to heroku: Environment data not found in the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to deploy my rails app to heroku which runs fine locally but I have so far been unable to migrate my database with heroku (fails with PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR). To amend this I have tried to follow suggestions to run:

```
heroku run rake db:reset --trace
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Running rake db:reset --trace on ⬢ parent-comms-app... up, run.6270
** Invoke db:reset (first_time)
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:check_protected_environments
D, [2016-07-28T13:10:17.703689 #3] DEBUG -- :   ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
D, [2016-07-28T13:10:17.722965 #3] DEBUG -- :    (1.0ms)  SELECT "ar_internal_metadata"."value" FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1  [["key", :environment]]
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

    bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=production

/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1256:in `last_stored_environment'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:48:in `check_protected_environments!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:209:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:186:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:209:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:207:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:186:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:drop => db:check_protected_environments
```

I have tried following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209186/rails-5-rspec-environment-data-not-found-in-the-schema) but with RAILS_ENV=production

My database.yml

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: parent_communication_development
    pool: 5
    username: Jack
    password:

test:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: parent_communication_test
    pool: 5
    username: Jack
    password:

production:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: parent_communication_production
    pool: 5
    username: Jack
    password: [I have set a password here]
```

I noticed that I had accidentally previously called my production database the same name as my development database but I have since changed that and reset the database locally/tried to amend this.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As advised I ran:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

But then I received an error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teachers" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "english_grades" ("id" serial primary key, "teacher_id" integer, "student_id" integer, "title" character varying, "subcategory" character varying, "performance_grade" character varying, "feedback" character varying, "grade_date" date, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7438078349"
FOREIGN KEY ("teacher_id")
  REFERENCES "teachers" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_023c49decc"
FOREIGN KEY ("student_id")
  REFERENCES "students" ("id")
)
```

Currently my migration for this table is

```
class CreateEnglishGrades < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change

    create_table :english_grades do |t|
      t.references :teacher, references: :users
      t.references :student, references: :users
      t.string :title
      t.string :subcategory
      t.string :performance_grade
      t.string :feedback
      t.date :grade_date

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :english_grades, :users, column: :teacher_id
    add_foreign_key :english_grades, :users, column: :student_id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with below command :

To drop the database:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
```

To recreate the database with nothing in it:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, resetting was successful but heroku run rake db:migrate failed with PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teachers" does not exist

Comment: just make sure teacher table create before  table contain foreign key of teacher table..

Comment: Sorry this was a mess, I edited it into my question above, do I need to modify the placement of the foreign keys?