# First db migration on Heroku: undefined table/relation doesn't exist for foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Error message: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "resolvers" does not exist`

Here's the migration that is spitting out the error:

```
class AddResolverRefToBugs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :bugs, :resolver, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Now, I get that there is no Resolver table, since the actual table is the User table; resolver_id is my foreign_key column.  So  I just have a `resolver_id` field for one of my models that references the Users model, and I've not had any issues with my app in the dev environment.

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resolver, class_name: 'User', optional: true
```

Am I supposed to specify something, somewhere such that PG would know :resolver (the resolver_id column) is in fact the Users table?

My error message contains the line: `: ALTER TABLE "bugs" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_2d3f1765bb" FOREIGN KEY ("resolver_id") REFERENCES "resolvers" ("id")`

So it does look like it's referencing the wrong thing.

In one relevant [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637655/deploying-rails-app-to-heroku-environment-data-not-found-in-the-schema), I noticed that he/she has "nested" references...

```
create_table :english_grades do |t|
  t.references :teacher, references: :users
  t.references :student, references: :users
```

...where users is specified.  I'm not sure if that is relevant here.

Presumably my schema my migration might have to look like:

`t.references :resolver, references: users`

The [docs for add_references](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_reference) don't mention anything about this.

That person also has foreign keys specified in the migration, where I do see a link that goes from the foreign key field to the actual table.  Presumably I'd need something like this:

`add_foreign_key :bugs, :users, column: :resolver_id`

But based on what I read online, it's not necessary to use `add_foreign_key`.

I would appreciate any explanation here.

Note: Some have suggested running db:reset first, but that doesn't work for me, as I get the [error this person is getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637655/deploying-rails-app-to-heroku-environment-data-not-found-in-the-schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still unsure as to why Postgres throws an error here while Sqlite does not.  However, one way to properly reference the resolver column to the Users table was using **foreign_key: {to_table: :users}**:

```
add_reference :bugs, :resolver, foreign_key: {to_table: :users}
```

After getting rid of the original `add_reference` migration.  PG did not complain while going through the migrations with this line.

(Rails 5)