# "Environment data not found in the schema." with database-cleaner when calling cucumber repeatedly on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, database-cleaner

**Note:** This is NOT a dupe of [Rails 5, Rspec: Environment data not found in the schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209186/rails-5-rspec-environment-data-not-found-in-the-schema), though it is similar.  The affected versions are different, and the solve doesn't work for me.

My Rails setup is as follows:

- Rails 6.0.1
- cucumber-rails 2.0.0
- database_cleaner 1.7.0

Whenever I run `cucumber` a second or subsequent time, I get this error:

```
3924 ~/fork/my-proj$ bundle exec cucumber
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

        rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test

/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1151:in `last_stored_environment'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:60:in `check_protected_environments!'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:15:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activerecord-6.0.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:491:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/grantb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Using the default profile...
[...cucumber continues as normal...]
```

**How the heck can I get rid of that?**

If I run `rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test`, it'll get rid of it for the next run of `cucumber`, but it will always come back on the run after that.

I found one other answer that suggested adding this to my config, but **it did exactly nothing**:

```
# This did NOT fix my problem:
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(
  :truncation,
  except: %w(ar_internal_metadata)
)
```

Clearly `database_cleaner` is deleting environment data, but I don't know how to make it stop.

Can anyone help me get rid of this annoying warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem was specific to `database_cleaner` 1.7.

A recent upgrade to 1.8.3 made this error stop happening.

([associated Github issue](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner-active_record/issues/15))