# While running specs entries are getting delete from schema migrations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner, ruby-on-rails-6.1

When upgraded to rails 6.1 my specs are failing due to entries are getting delete from schema_migrations table

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration.count
   (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS"
 => 1


ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError:

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run:

        bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test

Failure/Error: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError:


  Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

          bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

When I run the following command

```
    bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=test
```

It adds entry in the schema_migrations table.

But when I run

```
rspec spec/
```

It deleted all my entries from the schema_migrations table except 1 entry. I suspect the issue is in database cleaner. Also, I check few [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209186/rails-5-rspec-environment-data-not-found-in-the-schema) but so far no luck

rails_helper.rb

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'json_matchers/rspec'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

require 'database_cleaner'

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

#
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
  # arbitrary gems may also be filtered via:
  # config.filter_gems_from_backtrace("gem name")
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, expect: %w(ar_internal_metadata schema_migrations)
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.include RequestSpecHelper
  config.include ControllerSpecHelper
end
```

database_cleaner (2.0.1)
rails (6.1)
ruby (2.5.0)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (6.1.4)
ruby-oci8 (2.2.6.1)

Note: I am using oracle as a database

Comment: Have you run the suggested migration command (it does say that "Migrations are pending")? If that's not it, have you tried an explicit database reset for your test environment (`rails db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.

The schema_migrations table was cleaned as one of migration files had some advanced function in it, what is not supported by `db/schema.rb`

[Solution is to start use sql format](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps)

1. in `application.rb` add `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`
2. run dev server and rails will create for you `db/structure.sql`
3. delete schema.rb and run your tests now.

Answer (score 1):

To fixed this issue I have removed this line

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

Comment: Have you find out the reason? I feel so strange since `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` delete my test db  `ar_internal_metadata` and `schema_migrations` tables too.